# Perform animation on selected text

Tags: jquery, html

I want to be able to show/hide specific text (using jqery). The issue is that I will have more than one version of this text tag with the same id, and I want to be able to perform the animation on a specific child when you hover over the parent, and not perform it on all of the text blocks with the same id.

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<p>Move your cursor over the posts below to read more.</p>
<div id="postContainer">
    <div id="post">
        <h4>Title 1</h4>
        <h5>Date goes here</h5>
        <p id="postDetails">Blah Blah Blah, this text is hidden until you hover over it's own parent.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="postContainer">
    <div id="post">
        <h4>title 2</h4>
        <h5>Date goes here</h5>
        <p id="postDetails">This is the second hidden text, but it is revealed when you hover over the first post as well.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#post
{
    background:#DDDDDD;
}
#postDetails
{
    display"none;
}
```

Jquery:

```
<script>
    $('#post').mouseenter(function() {
      $('#postDetails').slideDown("slow");
    });
    $('#post').mouseleave(function() {
      $('#postDetails').slideUp("slow");
    });
</script>
```

Is there a way to reveal only one without creating a bunch of different div id with different names for each? There are 20-some boxes all like this (and they should all look identical) and I want to be able to reveal only one at a time, when the user hovers over that subsequent box, as revealing all 20 at the same time will greatly expand the page length and annoy the user.

Comment: If you have more than one element that are similar, don't use the same ID. Give them the same class name and use that to reference those elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have multiple elements then insted of using id's use class.

Please see the jsfiddle. I changed some markup.

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/saorabhkr/xtrpK/1/

Answer (score 1):

here is working demo

http://jsfiddle.net/CLgYB/

Explanation:

You need to use class for it..

HTML CODE

```
<p>Move your cursor over the posts below to read more.</p>
<div class="postContainer">
    <div class="post">
        <h4>Title 1</h4>
        <h5>Date goes here</h5>
        <p class="postDetails">Blah Blah Blah, this text is hidden until you hover over it's own parent.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="postContainer">
    <div class="post">
        <h4>title 2</h4>
        <h5>Date goes here</h5>
        <p class="postDetails">This is the second hidden text, but it is revealed when you hover over the first post as well.</p>
    </div>
</div>​
```

jQuery Script

$

```
('.post').mouseenter(function() {
      $(this).children('.postDetails').slideDown("slow");
    });
    $('.post').mouseleave(function() {
     $(this).children('.postDetails').slideUp("slow");
    });​
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use classes instead of ids. IDs should only be used for unique elements. You can loop through all your posts and add mouseenter and mouseleave events to each post. Use the this reference to target individual post and postDetails like so

```
$('.post').each(function(){
    $(this).mouseenter(function() {
      $(this).children('.postDetails').slideDown("slow");
    }).mouseleave(function() {
      $(this).children('.postDetails').slideUp("slow");
    });
});
​
```

I've put together a jsfiddle example here http://jsfiddle.net/pimlinders/b2ASK/
​

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#post').mouseenter(function() {


// while in here, the particular $('#post') which has been entered can be accessed as $(this)



     $(this).find('#postDetails').slideDown("slow");
});
```

...but you should really use different div id's.  that's why they're called ids.